# what is "s" , when extending jQuery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am testing how to extend Jquery selectors. I dont actually get what "s" is and what it does, so I decided to create a little code, to see for my self. I have this

```
//html part
<div id="one">scott</div>
<div id="two">scottpilgrim</div>
<div id="three">scottpilgrimvs</div>
<div id="four">scottpilgrimvstheworld</div>

//jquery part
    $.extend($.expr[':'],{
        findScott: function(e,i,m,s) {
            if($(e).text().indexOf(m[3]) > -1){
                return $(e);
                console.log(s);
            }
        }
    });

    //make it work once
    var test =$('div:findScott("vs")');
```

But when I run this, I see nothing in my Google Chrome console. What am I missing? What is "s" used for? What it contains? Is it an array? And why my console is empty?

Thanks

EDIT

After editing the code like the following, as Joe Enos suggested

```
if($(e).text().indexOf(m[3]) > -1){
                console.log(s);
                return $(e);

            }
```

I get this is my console, and cannot click it. What is this? Thanks

[image]

Comment: that simply means `s` is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Joe's answer explains why you aren't seeing anything in the console. I'll attempt to answer the main question from the title:

> what is “s” , when extending jQuery selectors

In older versions of jQuery, the fourth parameter is a collection containing all elements that are being tested, sometimes referred to as the 'stack'. In newer versions (both of jQuery 1.x and 2.x) it's no longer used.

You can see the difference when you run the code with different versions of jQuery.

```
if($(e).text().indexOf(m[3]) > -1){
    console.log(s);
    return $(e);
}
```

- [Demonstration using jQuery 1.6.4](http://jsfiddle.net/q8wm6/)
- [Demonstration using jQuery 2.1.0](http://jsfiddle.net/49mxz/)

Answer (score 4):

Your `console.log` line is after a `return` statement. It will never execute.

Comment: You make a lot of sense. Thanks. But the problem is , I see this in my console and I cannot click it. [see edit in my question] Why? Thanks again

Comment: If `s` is `undefined`, then apparently it's not used in that particular call. Can't help you there - you may have to end up digging into the jQuery source to see when and how it's used.